# Why i cant create a slot for my player so my enemy will chase or follow her?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

> the assertion is giving error and says Assertion failed. Value was
>   Null Expected: Value was not Null
>   UnityEngine.Assertions.Assert:IsNotNull(Transform)

```
public class EnemyMove : MonoBehaviour
{
private Transform Player;
private Animator anim;
private EnemyHealth enemyHealth;

void Awake()
{ 
    Assert.IsNotNull(Player); 
}
void Start()
{ 
    Player = GameManager.instance.Player.transform;
    enemyHealth = GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    nav = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>(); 
}

void Update()
{
    if (!GameManager.instance.GameOver && enemyHealth.IsAlive)
    {
        nav.SetDestination(player.position);
    }
    else if ((!GameManager.instance.GameOver || GameManager.instance.GameOver) && !enemyHealth.IsAlive)
    {
        nav.enabled = false;  
    }
    else
    {
        nav.enabled = false;
        anim.Play("Idle");   
    }  
}
}
```

Comment: If Zayed's answer works, please select it as the correct one by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

Awake() method is called before Start()
Assert.IsNotNull(Player); 
means that, Player can't be null.
But you are assigning Player later in Start() method, after using Assert in Awake() method.
You should use the Assert after this line:

```
Player = GameManager.instance.Player.transform;
```

Comment: didnt work i want my enemy to chase the player so i can assign the player in enemymove script of enemy but its not creating any slot to assign :(

Comment: It needs to be public. The editor only makes slots for public variables.